# How to silently install r-base in an ubuntu docker image

Tags: r, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, silent, silent-installer

I need to install `r-base` within an ubuntu:18.04 dockerimage. I am doing this while building my image via

```
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y r-base [many other packages]
```

along with many other package installations. The problem is, that while setting up r-base at the end of the installation process, it asks for user input for timezone followed by city within the specified timezone. I obviously cannot enter the data while building the container. How would I manage to install r-base anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909277/avoiding-user-interaction-with-tzdata-when-installing-certbot-in-a-docker-contai), you should set

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```